# Properly resolving multiple twttr.widgets.createTweet promises

Tags: javascript, twitter, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to add multiple tweets to a page as it is paginated. However, I cannot seem to get `widget.createTweet` promises to resolve in order to add their element to the page.

Here is the logic from my reduced [Codepen](https://codepen.io/BRacicot/pen/JjOwQmP) example.

```
 // increment current page number
 // create next set of tweets
 // append tweet elems to masonry container
 async function paginate() {
     let current = page;
     page = page + 3;
     var tweetIDs = source.slice(current, page);

     // create tweets/widget promises
     const tweetPromises = tweetIDs.map(async id => {
         // create grid element
         let gridEl = document.createElement("div");
         // set masonry class
         gridEl.setAttribute("class", "grid__item");
         // twitter widget.js - get promise
         const response = twttr.widgets.createTweet(id, gridEl, {
             theme: colorScheme,
             dnt: true
         });
         return response;
     });

     // Promise.all over loops
     let results = Promise.all(tweetPromises).then((m) => {
         console.log("then", m); // never happens
     })
     .catch(e => {
         console.log("catch", e.reason);
     });

     console.log(tweetIDs, tweetPromises, results, page);
     // need the resolved tweets first!
     // msnry.appended(newTweetElms);
     // msnry.addItems(newTweetElms);
     // msnry.layout();
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a problem with your use of promises; Twitter just won't resolve the promises unless the element you pass into `createWidget` is added to the DOM.

```js
let gridEl = document.createElement("div");
document.querySelector("#twitter").appendChild(gridEl);
```

Other than that, your code looks fine, aside from your use of `then`/`catch` in an `async` function. (It works, but it can be confusing, because you've got two different styles of asynchronous behavior.) This, for instance, makes it less obvious that your final diagnostic `console.log` will *always* show a Promise for `results`. If you were to log `await results` (and drop your "never happens" `then` and `catch` logging) your final `console.log` would show your array of actual elements.